# Django Admin, how to replace the user status sign

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

In the django admin, the super user column, is showing these two signs [image]

How can I replace them with text?

Comment: It would help if you showed some code. How are you displaying the super user column? It isn't displayed by default.

Comment: list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'email',  'date_joined', 'is_superuser',)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a model admin method that returns the text you require, then include it in [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def is_superuser_text(self, obj):
        return 'True' if obj.is_superuser else 'False'            
    is_superuser_text.short_description = 'Is Superuser'
    is_superuser_text.admin_order_field = 'is_superuser'

    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'is_superuser_text',)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks, but ordering is disabled; how can i enable it again?

Comment: Set `admin_order_field`.

Comment: It does the trick, but when i click on it, i get this ''tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'' error.

Comment: Sounds like you've made a typo